# Want to convert Excel data into RDF

Tags: excel, rdf, semantic-web, protege

I am using protege for converting my Excel file which contain around about 60,000 data. I am using protege plugin for creating axioms from Excel data. I have created a script .json to specify the rules. But the problem is that. It takes almost 20 minutes to convert only 6-7 rows.

Is it depending upon laptop speed?

How can I speed up this?

Comment: If possible please show your .json script and the full reference to the plugins to help other users consider an answer.

Comment: Which plugin? https://github.com/protegeproject/cellfie-plugin?